# Manipulating the UI from a worker thread

Tags: android, multithreading

The Andoid UI toolkit is not thread-safe, when you try to modify the UI from a worker thread you get the `CalledFrowWrongThreadException` (or something like that).

Moreover, the dev guide say:

> [Manipulating the UI from a worker thread] can result in undefined and
>   unexpected behavior, which can be
>   difficult and time-consuming to track
>   down.

But it does not seem to me very difficult to understand what a `CalledFrowWrongThreadException` mean.

Does the documentation was written before the introduction of `CalledFrowWrongThreadException` or are there still cases where the exception is not thrown? (or where the error is indeed difficult and time-consuming to track down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is that checking what thread is calling a given function incurs a processing overhead; there are almost certainly calls that don't check for precisely this reason - it would slow down the UI rendering.

By extension, the reason UI functions aren't thread-safe is that if you through mutex code into the equation, the performance hit becomes even greater.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Swing in Java, and WinForms in .NET, there *may* be cases where the method in question does not check to determine that you are calling from the proper thread, and therefore does not *necessarily* throw the expected exception.

Providing the above documentation is a way to cover themselves and explain a simple idea that actually requires a lot of effort to work around if you do not know it, or understand it, *before* the wrong thread exception is ever thrown by offending code, which may be much later down the road.